# How to use Azure App Configuration Service with Azure Functions in local dev environment?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-app-configuration, azure-functions-isolated

I am writing an Azure Function (Service Bus Topic Triggered Function in isolated mode) which is part of a bigger solution that has API and other projects. The API reads the configuration settings from Azure App Configuration Service and that is working fine.

What I want to do is read the settings in my Function from there and set the bindings for the Function based on those settings however it is not working.

Here's what I did:

- I created an App Configuration Service in my Azure Subscription and added the configuration keys there.

[image]

- Then I added the reference to this App Configuration Service in `Program.cs` using the code like below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(
            "Endpoint=https://myfunctionconfig.azconfig.io;Id=somerandomstring;Secret=otherrandomstring",
            optional: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
    })
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

- My Function code looks something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ServiceBusTriggeredFunction;

public static class ServiceBusTopicTrigger
{
    [Function("ServiceBusTopicTrigger")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Topic%", "%FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Subscription%", Connection = "FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Connection")] string mySbMsg,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var logger = context.GetLogger("ServiceBusTopicTrigger");
        logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
    }
}
```

However when I run the code locally, I am getting the following error:

> The 'ServiceBusTopicTrigger' function is in error:
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
> 'Functions.ServiceBusTopicTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
> '%FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Topic%' does not
> resolve to a value.

Basically the issue is that it is not able to read the settings value (`FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Topic`).

However the same code works flawlessly if I define the same settings in `local.settings.json`.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Connection": "Endpoint=sb://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=myaccesskey=",
        "FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Topic": "topic",
        "FunctionsConfiguration:ServiceBusTopicTrigger:Subscription": "subscription"
    }
}
```

I am wondering if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here and if there's a way for me to read the settings from an App Configuration Service (I guess the same would apply to `appsettings.json` as well) and set the Function bindings based on the settings.

Comment: you'll need to make sure that the configuration values are available to the Function when it's running.
I Suggest a log or breakpoint to make sure and see if the configuration values are being loaded correctly

Comment: @1SaeedSalehi - Thanks. You make an interesting point. What I am noticing is that my code in `ServiceBusTopicTrigger` is executed before the code in `Program.cs`. That could very well be the reason. How can I ensure that the Function is triggered after the code in `Program.cs`? Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on Github here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1437 and this is the response I got there:

> worker configuration sources are not currently supported by
> extensions/bindings, as that configuration must be available at the
> app/platform level (platform components depend on that configuration).
>
> Currently, your best option would be to use the feature described
> here:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configuration-references

Comment: That linked ticket and page from MS isn't a very helpful answer (comment at them, not you). It talks about references using `@Microsoft.AppConfiguration` ... and not '%key%'... so exactly how does someone get from using variables with percentage characters (e.g. '%key%') to what ever works?