# Azure function QueueTrigger binding with custom configuration file? (c#)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have an Azure func app (.net6 + isolated) with a bunch of different triggers (mostly http)
**I want to add another function that listens to a specific azure cloud queue (QueueTrigger)** like this:
[image]

It works, but queue name (+ connection string) is hard coded.
Also I want to use different account for dev and prod.
**I know we can use local.setting.js and %pattern% to get values from "Values" object**.
**The problem is - I'm already using custom json file for configuration - appSettings.json (appSetting.Development.json) and want to keep the config approach consistent**.
Here is a code from entry point:
[image]

There is also a way to inject IBinder to the QueueTrigger method, but if I'm not mistaken it makes sense only for output bindings... correct my if I'm wrong, please...

Another workaround would be to create a TimerTrigger function and check for new messages manually (e.g., ones per 5 mins), but this approach does not scale well :)

Appreciate any thoughts/suggestions, even if the only one is "no, it's not possible" :)
Thank you!

Comment: Currently it is not possible to do so. I asked the same question just a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75815924/how-to-use-azure-app-configuration-service-with-azure-functions-in-local-dev-env.